# Android Device 4.4.4 Google Play Services

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-gradle-plugin

I am developing an Android app and want to support back to API version 15.

The device I'm running has Android version 4.4.4

Google Play service is install on the device with version 4.4.52

What dependency do I need to add to my gradle? I've tried a bunch but haven't had luck:

Example:

**1)**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:6.+'
```

This compiles however it fails on run saying play services needs an update.

**2)**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:4.4.52'
```

This doesn't compile and I get the following error that I'm unsure how to fix.

```
google play services 4.4.52 attribute "theme" has already been defined
```

Here is a list of my entire Gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile 'org.parceler:parceler:0.2.13'
compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:6.+'
```

Comment: `This compiles however it fails on run saying play services needs an update` so why dont you update google play services??

Comment: Do you mean update google play services on my device? The goal is to support people who may have the version of my device. I can't expect everyone to have updated correct

Comment: if you want granular use of google play services ie. only using the API's you want from google play services you need to use the newest. Otherwise you need to declare google play services that includes everything

Comment: BTW the version of google play services does not indicate what version OS the user has on their device, someone with 4.0 might not have version 4.4 of GPS.

Comment: So are you saying its not possible to use GPS with the version on my device?

Comment: I'm trying to simply use the location service retrieve the users latitude/longitude when opening the app

Comment: that is not at all what I said. If you are trying to just use the location api of GPS you need to upgrade. If you dont want to upgrade you need to declare google play services in a way that will give you all of GPS API's. you can only target specific api's in newer versions

Comment: Ok no problem... so what specifically do I need to declare google play services as without upgrading?

Comment: you need to declare GPS in general form like this `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'` https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: ... i'm confused, that would require me to update GPS on my device, correct? which I'm not sure I want to do. Again, the goal is to not use the latest version for fear that users won't have it

Comment: so use whatever version you want its an example. its always better to have the latest one anyway

Comment: the whole point of my post was to understand which version I need to be using with what's installed on the device

Comment: When I try and load in the specific version GPS 4.4.52 I get the following error. Any idea why? com.google.android.gms\play-services\4.4.52\res\values\wallet_colors.xml 
Error:(1) Attribute "theme" has already been defined

Comment: that might not be an actual version, there is no list of previous versions that google provides that I know of

Comment: Not an actual version?? It's literally on my phone and says 4.4.52

Comment: phone version does not indicate API version they release updates for bug fixes

Comment: seriously you are better off using the newest

Comment: So if I use 7.5.0 as you suggest that means everyone who uses the app has to have 7.5.0 installed, seems like that's not going to be the case

Comment: if they dont have the latest that means they literally cannot use any google apps because they always support the latest. anytime you launch one of their apps it will check for it. Also you will have any and all bug fixes they made since then and there have been a lot especially with the location api

Comment: ah....... Ok so forgive me as I'm new to android dev and never owned one before... so basically this phone I have (was just a hand me down) is just way out of date and hasn't ran a google app in a while. Do I have that correct?

Comment: I'm confused again... I'm opening a bunch of Google Apps that are on the phone (example Play stand and Play games) and it's not asking me to update

Comment: FYI updating my device to the latest google play services fixed this, however I'm still unclear on the update path you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use: `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0`.

To get the following info: Google Location, Activity Recognition, and Places.

GooglePlay Service is compatible to Android device that runs Android 2.3 or higher and includes Google Play Store.

All info about GooglePlay Service SDK, you can look at: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: But what if google play services version 7.5.0 is not installed on the user's device ?